# Render page rails, modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, modal-dialog, render

I am currently trying to optimize rendering a page in ruby on rails.

I have a question, is there a way to make a page, only render another page when a link (href) associated to it is clicked.

some codes in index.html.erb:

```
.....   
.....
<h4>
  <%= item.name %>
  <br/><a href="#<%=itemt.id%>_item_modal">Details</a>
</h4>

<div id="<%=item.id%>_item_modal" class="modal fullscreen">
  <div class="item-modal">
    <%=render item%>
  </div>
</div>
.....
.....
```

In code above, I am using modal. So that when the link is clicked, _item.html.erb will be shown appear in a smaller page. Similar like a popup.

When index.html.erb is loaded, then all codes inside _item.html.erb will also be loaded automatically and all queries inside will be executed because of

```
<%render item%>
```

code.

What I want is, I don't want index.html.erb also render all item inside _item.html.erb page unless I click "Details" button.

```
<br/><a href="#<%=itemt.id%>_item_modal">Details</a>
```

I think by doing this think, I can save some amount of time when a user requests for item page, because the system doesn't need to retrieve all information which are not yet required.

Could you guys help me?

Please let me know if you need another information.

Comment: You can use Ajax to retrieve all information on clicking on the link

Comment: From what I can read you are already making a call to the DB for all the information. You can do what you are asking with ajax like Salil said but it doesn't sound like it is worth it for what you are doing. I would add a layer of caching to speed things up. Unless the details call is really expensive...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ajax in order to achieve this. You can create a hidden div with a specific id, say "modal".

Revert your h4 to this:

```
<h4>
  <%= item.name %>
  <br/>
  = link_to 'Details', item_path(item), data: {remote: true}, item_details: true
</h4>
```

Then in your item controller, on the show action:

```
def show
  # load the item
  if params[:item_details]
    respond_to {|format| format.js}
  else
    # do what you already do here
  end
end
```

And in your item views folder, create a file show.js(.coffee):

```
$('#modal').html('<%= j(render partial: "item", object: @item) %>');
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

This is just the idea, you have to make it compatible with your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the ajax route:

```
<h4>
  <%= item.name %>
  <br/>
  <%= link_to "Details", item_path(item), remote: true %>
</h4>
```

Then in your items_controller:

```
def show
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then create the view "views/items/show.js"

```
$(body).append(<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "items/item_modal") %>);
...code to show modal...
...hook to remove modal when it is dismissed...
```

And the view "views/items/_item_modal.html.erb"

```
<div id="<%=item.id%>_item_modal" class="modal fullscreen">
  <div class="item-modal">
    <%=render item%>
  </div>
</div>
```